# ¿Cómo obtengo los textos que estén entre dos pares de saltos de línea (\r\n\r\n)?

Tags: python, regex

Quisiera una expresión regular que, a través de `findall()`, me devolviera una lista con todos los textos que estén entre 2 pares de saltos de lineas de Windows (precedido y sucedido por `'\r\n\r\n'`), pero que lo haga en base a las siguientes condiciones:

- Que no devuelva la última coincidencia con la expresión.
- Si es la única coincidencia, retornarla.
- El texto puede contener caracteres alfanuméricos y espacios (incluyendo los saltos de lineas)

## Ejemplo 1

**Del texto**

```
text =  (
    '\r\n\r\n'
    'S0y único'
    '\r\n\r\n'
)
```

**Obtener**

```
['S0y único']
```

## Ejemplo 2

**Del texto**

```
text =  (
    'No quiero est0'
    '\r\n\r\n'
    'Quiero e5to'
    '\r\n\r\n'
    'Esto no me sirve'
    '\r\n'
)
```

**Obtener**

```
['Quiero e5to']
```

## Ejemplo 3

**Del texto**

```
text =  (
    '\r\n'
    'No quiero esto'
    '\r\n\r\n'
    'soy la \r\n primera coincidenci4'
    '\r\n\r\n'
    'soy la \r\n ultima coincidenci4'
    '\r\n\r\n'
    'Esto no me sirve'
)
```

**Obtener**

```
['soy la \r\n primera coincidenci4']
```

## Ejemplo 4

**Del texto**

```
text =  (
    '\r\n'
    'No quiero esto'
    '\r\n\r\n'
    'faaaa \r\n feeeee \r\n fiiiiii \r\n fooo \r\n p170'
    '\r\n\r\n'
    'faaaa \r\n feeeee \r\n fiiiiii \r\n fooo \r\n fuuuu \r\n f4ck'
    '\r\n\r\n'
    'yo no \r\n voy a estar'
    '\r\n\r\n'
)
```

**Obtener**

```
[
     'faaaa \r\n feeeee \r\n fiiiiii \r\n fooo \r\n p170'
     'faaaa \r\n feeeee \r\n fiiiiii \r\n fooo \r\n fuuuu \r\n f4ck'
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
\A[^\r\n]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[^\r\n]*)*\r\n\r\n([\w \t\f]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[\w \t\f]*)*)(?=\r\n\r\n)|\r\n\r\n([\w \t\f]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[\w \t\f]*)*)(?=[\s\S]*?\r\n\r\n[\w \t\f]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[\w \t\f]*)*\r\n\r\n)
```

Son 2 opciones:

- Para el primer ítem: `\A[^\r\n]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[^\r\n]*)*\r\n\r\n([\w \t\f]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[\w \t\f]*)*)(?=\r\n\r\n)`

  - `\A` - inicio del string
  - `[^\r\n]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[^\r\n]*)*` - cualquier cantidad de caracteres siempre que no haya un doble salto de línea
  - `\r\n\r\n` - un doble salto de línea
  - `([\w \t\f]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[\w \t\f]*)*)` - Grupo 1, esto es lo que se captura y se devuelve

    - `[\w \t\f]*` cualquier cantidad de caracteres alfanuméricos o espacios en blanco excepto saltos de línea
    - `(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[\w \t\f]*)*` - opcionalmente más saltos de líneas que no son dobles, seguidos de más alfanuméricos o espacios en blanco
    - `(?=\r\n\r\n)` - seguido de otro salto de línea doble
- Para sucesivos ítems: `\r\n\r\n([\w \t\f]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[\w \t\f]*)*)(?=[\s\S]*?\r\n\r\n[\w \t\f]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[\w \t\f]*)*\r\n\r\n)`

  - Sigue la misma estructura de la opción 1, excepto que no está anclada a `\A`, y debe cumplir la condición:
  - `(?=[\s\S]*?\r\n\r\n[\w \t\f]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[\w \t\f]*)*\r\n\r\n)` - seguido por otro ítem entre dobles saltos de línea.

Código:

```
import re

text =  (
    '\r\n'
    'No quiero esto'
    '\r\n\r\n'
    'faaaa \r\n feeeeeé \r\n fiiiiii \r\n fooo \r\n p170'
    '\r\n\r\n'
    'faaaa \r\n feeeee \r\n fiiiiii \r\n fooo \r\n fuuuu \r\n f4óck'
    '\r\n\r\n'
    'yo no \r\n voy a estar'
    '\r\n\r\n'
)


regex = r"\A[^\r\n]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[^\r\n]*)*\r\n\r\n([\w \t\f]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[\w \t\f]*)*)(?=\r\n\r\n)|\r\n\r\n([\w \t\f]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[\w \t\f]*)*)(?=[\s\S]*?\r\n\r\n[\w \t\f]*(?:\r\n(?!\r\n)[\w \t\f]*)*\r\n\r\n)"

resultado = re.findall(regex, text)

print(resultado)
```

Resultado:

```
[('faaaa \r\n feeeeeé \r\n fiiiiii \r\n fooo \r\n p170', ''), ('', 'faaaa \r\n feeeee \r\n fiiiiii \r\n fooo \r\n fuuuu \r\n f4óck')]
```

Demo:

https://ideone.com/Vb2lTb